# Associate scene with workspace

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor, workflow, scene, workspaces

I'm looking for an approach to have my scenes associated/linked to certain workspaces.
Say for instance, I do work in the VSE on 'scene x', then go back to 'scene y' where I continue some modelling. Each time I go from one scene to another, I have to switch workspace.
Is there any add-ons or techniques to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an explanation and an add-on here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnsvgcgnfGE
Add-on: https://github.com/metaperson/blender_vse/blob/main/tube/20211113%231/workspace_glue-timer.py

And there is a patch, which apparently has stalled:
https://developer.blender.org/D9140

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad I'm not the only one annoyed by this.. :) From your last comment, you mean it used to work like this back in previous versions?